# How does compiler decides when to use a vPtr to invoke a function

Tags: c++

How to identify whether vptr will be used to invoke a virtual function?

Consider the below hierarchy:

```
class A
{
    int n;
 public:
    virtual void funcA()
    {std::cout <<"A::funcA()" << std::endl;}
};

class B: public A
{
  public:
   virtual void funcB()
   {std::cout <<"B::funcB()" << std::endl;}
};

A* obj = new B();

obj->funcB(); //1. this does not even compile

typedef void (*fB)();
fB* func;
int* vptr = (int*)obj; //2.  Accessing the vptr 

func = (fB*)(*vptr);
func[1](); //3. Calling funcB using vptr.
```

Statement 1. i.e. obj->funcB(); does not even compile although Vtable has an entry for funcB where as on accessing vPtr indirectly funcB() can be invoked successfully.

How does compiler decide when to use the vTable to invoke a function?
In the statement A* obj = new B(); since I am using a base class pointer so I believe vtable should be used to invoke the function.

Below is the memory layout when vptr is accessed indirectly.[image: Memory layout]

Comment: The line that follows (2) exhibits undefined behavior. "Seems to work" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior.

Comment: Of course it doesn't compile. There is no `A::funcB()`.

Comment: `How does compiler decide when to use the vTable to invoke a function?` It decides to do so when doing so is necessary to satisfy the prescribed semantics of the C++ language. Why exactly do you care about thse implementation details? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: In `obj->funcB();`, for all the compiler knows `obj` actually points to an instance of `A`, or an instance of yet another class `C` derived from `A`. There's no indication that `B` is anywhere in the picture, that the call to `funcB` is at all meaningful.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik What do you mean "In obj->funcB();, for all the compiler knows obj actually points to an instance of yet another class C derived from A."

Comment: @DonLarynx I mean what I say - which part, specifically, do you find unclear? `obj` is of type `A*`, so it can point to an object of class `A` or any class derived from `A`.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik: I know the behaviour is undefined , it may or may not work on some environment. I am not trying to solve any problem, I am just trying to find out the cases when we can't take for granted that vptr will be used even if accessing the derived type from a base type is satisfied.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik This means that it can point to an instance of B since B is derived from A. B is in the picture.

Comment: It is simply not allowed to call a function that doesn't exist for the (static) type of the object. Virtual functions only tell the compiler to defere the decision of which function to call (`A::foo` or `B::foo`) to the runtime and vPtr is one possible way to implement that mechanism. In your example however, there is no reason to use virtual functions at all, because you don't override them anyway.

Comment: @DonLarynx It can, but it doesn't have to. That's why the call to `funcB` is syntactically invalid. Suppose this line compiled - what would you expect to happen when this line is executed at run-time, and `obj` does not in fact point to a `B`? If you want a dynamically typed language, there is no shortage of those - but C++ is not one of them.

Comment: `the cases when we can't take for granted that vptr will be used` You can never take for granted that vptr will be used. It's an internal implementation detail. You can take for granted that a well-formed C++ program will exhibit observable behavior consistent with that prescribed by the C++ language specification.

Comment: @MikeMB: Virtual functions tell the compiler to defer the decision to runtime and how does compiler do that by augmenting the source code and adding code to rather use vTable to access the function at runtime. So in this case if compiler adds code using vPtr it will definitely find the funcB in vTable but it seems compiler doesn't do that . So my question does compiler also checks to see if the function is overridden or not?

Answer (score 2):

So there are two answers to your question:

1. The short one is:
   `obj->FuncB()` is only a legal call, if the *static* type of `obj` (in this case `A`) has a function `FuncB` with the appropriate signature (either directly or due to a base class). Only if that is the case, the compiler decides whether it translates it to a direct or dynamic function call (e.g. using a vtable), based on whether `FuncB` is declared virtual or not in the **declaration of `A`** (or its base type).
2. The longer one is this:
   When the compiler sees `obj->funcB()` it has no way of knowing (optimizations aside), what the runtime type of obj is and especially it doesn't know, whether a derived class that implements `funcB()` exists, at all. `obj` might e.g. be created in another translation unit or it might be a function parameter.

   And no, that information is usually not stored in the virtual function table:
   The vtable is just an array of addresses and without the **prior knowledge** that a specific addess corresponds to a function called `funcB`, the compiler can't use it to implement the call `obj->funcB()`- or to be more precise: it is not allowed to do so by the standard. That prior knowledge can only be provided by a virtual function declaration in the static type of `obj` (or its base classes).

   The reason, why you have that information available in the debugger (whose behavior lys outside of the standard anyway) is, because it has access to the debugging symbols, which are usually not part of the distributed release binary. Storing that information in the vtable by default, would be a waste of memory and performance, as the program isn't allowed to make use of it in standard c++ in the way you describe anyway. For extensions like C++/CLI that might be a different story.

Comment: @anonymous: Your welcome - feel free to accept it if you think it answers your question completely.

Comment: @MikeMB So regarding possible optimizations, more or less you could say that if the the object you're invoking a method on is KNOWN (somehow through optimizations) to be of the same type as its pointer (namely no upcasting has taken place) the function call could be resolved statically, else, it could have been upcasted so we better consult the vtable (resolve in a polymorphic manner)?

Comment: @DomFarolino: Exactly, afaik this is called devirtualization

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Barry's comment, adding the line `virtual void funcB() = 0;` to `class A` seems to fix the problem.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.